# if writable form validation not working CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble setting the if writable form validation for my form.

I know codeigniter form validation is post. I thought this might be able to work.

I need to be able to display my errors if file or folder is not writable `chomd 644 or 777`

Currently know errors are showing up.

I have form validation library and form autoloaded.

**Controller**

```
<?php 

class Step2 extends MX_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->lang->load('install/english', 'english');

        $this->lang->load('install/english', 'english');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cache', 'Cache', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('logs', 'Logs', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('logs', 'Logs', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('modules/download', 'modules/download', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('modules/image', 'modules/image', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('modules/image/cache', 'modules/image/cache', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('modules/image/catalog', 'modules/image/catalog', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('step3'));

        } else {

        $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_step_2'));

        $data['config'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'config/config.php';

        $data['cache'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'cache';
        $data['logs'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'logs';
        $data['download'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/download';
        $data['image'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/image';
        $data['image_cache'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/image/cache';
        $data['image_data'] = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/image/catalog';

        if (is_really_writable(APPPATH . 'cache') == false) {
            echo "Cache Folder is not writable";
            echo "</br>";
        } 

        if (is_really_writable(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'logs') == false) {
            echo "Logs Folder is not writable";
            echo "</br>";
        }

        if (is_really_writable(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/download') == false) {
            echo "Downloads Folder is not writable";
            echo "</br>";
        }

        if (is_really_writable(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/image') == false) {
            echo "Image Folder is not writable";
            echo "</br>";
        }

        if (is_really_writable(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/image/cache') == false) {
            echo "Image Cache Folder is not writable";
            echo "</br>";
        }

        if (is_really_writable(FCPATH . APPPATH . 'modules/image/catalog') == false) {
            echo "Downloads file is not writable";
            echo "</br>";
        }

        $data['back'] = $this->url->link('step1');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('template/step2', $data));

        }

    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><?php echo $text_install_directory; ?></p>
        <fieldset>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td align="left"><b><?php echo $text_directory; ?></b></td>
                <td align="left"><b><?php echo $text_status; ?></b></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $cache . '/'; ?></td>
                <td name="cache"><?php if (is_writable($cache)) { ?>
                  <span class="text-success"><?php echo $text_writable; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $text_unwritable; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $logs . '/'; ?></td>
                <td name="logs"><?php if (is_writable($logs)) { ?>
                  <span class="text-success"><?php echo $text_writable; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $text_unwritable; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $download . '/'; ?></td>
                <td><?php if (is_writable($download)) { ?>
                  <span class="text-success"><?php echo $text_writable; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $text_unwritable; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $image . '/'; ?></td>
                <td><?php if (is_writable($image)) { ?>
                  <span class="text-success"><?php echo $text_writable; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $text_unwritable; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $image_cache . '/'; ?></td>
                <td><?php if (is_writable($image_cache)) { ?>
                  <span class="text-success"><?php echo $text_writable; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $text_unwritable; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $image_data . '/'; ?></td>
                <td><?php if (is_writable($image_data)) { ?>
                  <span class="text-success"><?php echo $text_writable; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $text_unwritable; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="pull-left"><a href="<?php echo $back; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $button_back; ?></a></div>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

My Update I can now get errors showing I had to add this on controller.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cache', '', 'callback_isWritable');

public function isWritable() {
$folder_cache = FCPATH . APPPATH . 'cache';

if (is_writable($folder_cache )) {
return true;
} else {
$this->form_validation->set_message('isWritable', 'Cache Folder ' . '<b>' . $folder_cache . '</b>' . ' is not writable');
return false;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a custom callback to use for this.

you need to create a function like this in the same class as the validation code.

```
//by adding the extra underscore the method is not reachable from the browser
public function _isWritable($filename)
{
    if (! is_really_writable(APPPATH . 'cache')) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('isWritable', 'Cache Folder is not writable');

        return false;
    }

    //additional if statements to check each of the additional folders...

   return true;
}
```

then you would just add it to the rules like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('saveChecks', '', 'callback__isWritable');
```

and you can output the form error for this by doing

```
echo form_error('saveChecks');
```

Comment: I will give it ago and will let you know how I go. also I use hmvc so will have to use run($this) with MY_Form_Validation.

Comment: No luck on displaying the errors on view did what you said. I also tried it for `APPPATH . 'config/database.php'`

Comment: On view now I have `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.` in validation area `<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>`

Comment: I have updated my post I have got errors working but just now have to figure out how to add 777 on xampp for folder permissions.

Comment: @acoderslife sorry about vanishing, I had to go into a meeting. Im glad you got it sorted out